# How to make ImageMagick only replace the file if its size is actually reduced by the conversion?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to optimize for size a few thousand jpg files uploaded to my web site by the users. Obviously it's going to be a batch job.

My experiments with Google Pagespeed suggestions so far show that many files can be reduced in size quite dramatically but some files apparently are already optimized so well that the convert/mogrify result is actually larger than the source file. I don't want to replace smaller files with larger files, I would prefer to just leave them as they are.

The question: is there by any chance a command line option I am missing that would suppress file replacement if the result is larger than the source? Or I will have to do it in my shell script?